# Node JS "dynamically" write/update Firebase node

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am wanting to update a Firebase Node called `BoxScores` which will hold four values of `Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4`

Below is the code im trying to implement to do so, where `qtrDesc` is the holder of the `Q1 or Q2 or Q3 or Q4`:

```
for(let i = body[key]["qtr"]; i > 0; i--) {

   let qtrDesc = "Q".concat(i);

   ref.child("BoxScores").update({

       qtrDesc: body[key]["home"]["score"][i] + ":" + body[key]["away"]["score"][i]

   }).catch(err => {

       console.log("Error updating BoxScores node: ", err);

   });
}
```

The problem with the code above is that when the update gets executed it places `qtrDesc` in the `BoxScores` node instead of the `Q1, Q2, Q3 or Q4` values I want or expected!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use `[]` notation to use the variable as the key in your updates:

```
var updates = {};
updates[qtrDesc] = body[key]["home"]["score"][i] + ":" + body[key]["away"]["score"][i];
ref.child("BoxScores").update(updates).catch(err => {...
```

Comment: Follow-up question in regards to firebase triggers. I wish to read the value based on the computation as such: `let qtrDesc = "Q".concat(1);

console.log('****BoxScore Info Qtr: ', newValue.qtrDesc);`

Comment: how can I modify your response if I needed to update two children in that dynamic `[]` notation!? In my example it only updates `Q1 = 2:14` but how do I modify your response if I want the above but also want to update a child timestamp like `lastupdate : firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`

Comment: `updates["lastupdate"] = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`